# Strange error downloading files with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, download, express, mongoose

This is the Node.JS code, it has two parts. The first one is in the main server file:

```
app.get('/download/:photo', function (req, res){ 

   dbs.imagenschema.find({ _id: req.params.photo }, function (err, imagen){

     if (err) throw assert.ifError(err);;

     var file = __dirname + '/public/users/' + imagen.auid + '/' + imagen.name;

     var filename = path.basename(file);
     var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

     res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
     res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

     var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
     filestream.pipe(res);

   });

});
```

The other part is the `dbs.imagenschema`, but that part is very simple, it's just the schema for the images exported from `dbs` module.

This is te button that when is clicked, the download starts:

```
<a href="/download/<%= photo._id %>">
  <button class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-download-alt icon-white"></i>  Download</button>
</a>
```

But, when I click it, I receive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'background' of null
  at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/root/pixgalery/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:234:12), <anonymous>:30:4196)
  at /root/pixgalery/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:239:15
  at Object.exports.render (/root/pixgalery/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:277:13)
  at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/root/pixgalery/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:303:22)
  at View.render (/root/pixgalery/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:75:8)
  at Function.app.render (/root/pixgalery/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:500:10)
  at ServerResponse.res.render (/root/pixgalery/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:717:7)
  at /root/pixgalery/app.js:181:15
  at Promise.<anonymous> (/root/pixgalery/db.js:237:27)
  at Promise.<anonymous> (/root/pixgalery/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:133:8)
```

So, I think is because of this:

```
app.get('/:user/:id', function (req, res){

  dbs.getimage(req.params.id, req.params.user, function (user, img, fav, comments){

    if (img.type == 'music') {

      res.render('music.ejs', {

            user: user,
            photo: img,
            req: req.session.user,
            fav: fav,
            comments: comments

        });

    } else{

      res.render('photo.ejs', {

            user: user,
            photo: img,
            req: req.session.user,
            fav: fav,
            comments: comments

      });

    }

  });

});
```

Maybe the server thinks that the `/download/fooid` is a request for the code I've writted above, because, the `/download/fooid` doesn't send any response with an EJS file, so, is impossible to get an error like that. Any solution for this?

Thank's advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure the `/download/:photo` route is declared before the `/:user/:id` route, otherwise the latter will *also* match `/download/fooid`, thinking that `download` is the user parameter and `fooid` is the `id` parameter (with Express, matching occurs in order of declaration: the first route which matches a request will get to handle it).

So:

```
// first this...
app.get('/download/:photo', ...);

// ...and then this.
app.get('/:user/:id', ...);
```

Comment: I tried it in my VPS, and then, doesn't work. But in local works

Comment: Do you access the Node on your VPS directly, or via something like nginx? Perhaps something is caching the original faulty responses?